# How to upgrade/update online accounts software in ubuntu 11.10 to that available in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, online-accounts

The online accounts software present is latest release is very cool, is it possible to update that software in ubuntu 11.10 without having to upgrade to 12.10.

Comment: The software repositories are specific to each release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

No not possible. Ubuntu webapps are only available for 12.10 (default) & 12.04 (via ppa)